# Cannot delete from sql using @Transactional with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate

I have @Transactional set up correctly, however with the following method "success" is returned but the record is not deleted from the table:

```
@Transactional
public void deleteLimXrefHvo(LimitXrefHvo limitXrefHvo){
    getSession().delete(getTableId(limitXrefHvo));
}
```

I tried with the method getTableId annotated with @Transactional as well and that does not solve the problem.  I've also called getTableId and stored the return value in a variable before passing it into delete() and that did not work, either.

The only thing that works that I've tried is to add getSession().flush(); after the delete transaction.  If I have @Transactional set up, then I shouldn't need to flush after.  What am I missing?

Comment: After the `delete`, try adding a `find` for the same element. Is this in a Unit test or normal code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was getTableId that was causing the problem. getTableId calls its own getSession(), and because of that, I have to flush(). there is no getting around it. makes sense, though.

Answer (score 0):

The session may live longer than a single transaction. This seems to be the case here. From the [JSR-220](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr220/index.html) 5.6:

> A container-managed persistence context may be defined to have either
>   a lifetime that is scoped to a single transaction or an extended
>   lifetime that spans multiple transactions, depending on the
>   PersistenceContextType that is specified when its EntityManager is
>   created. This specification refers to such persistence contexts as
>   transaction-scoped persistence contexts and extended persistence
>   contexts respectively.

I know you said 'Spring' and not Java EE container but I believe it boils down to the same behavior.

This is to say that session-scope is not equal transaction-scope. For your specific problem you may check:

- Is ´deleteLimXrefHvo()´ called from another `@Transactional` method (hint: what about transaction propagation)?
- What flush mode does the transaction have (manual?)?

Investigate your logs, in particular I would set the logging level to `DEBUG` on your transaction manager to see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Is that a glitch then?  I don't see how I declare that the method is transactional and then, what, Java *decides* on its own that it's not?